# Detecting when a subscription is cancelled in Meteor

Tags: meteor

How can I detect when a subscription is cancelled?

There are many ways it can be cancelled and I would like to analyze cancellation/subscription behavior.

Comment: Do you mean when `.stop` is called, to find a way to notify the client?

Comment: @Akshat, I meant any way. For instance stop, cancellation by server, invalidation of computation...

Answer (score 1):

Set a handle to your collection subscription, e.g.

```
var subHandle = Meteor.subscribe('subscription-name')
```

Subscription handles have a method called *ready()* that is a reactive data source. If the subscription has been cancelled, it will return **false**. Because it is a reactive data source, you could place an *if* statement inside a reactive computation to detect when the the subscription is cancelled.

Example:

```
Deps.autorun(function() {
  if (subHandle && (! subHandle.ready())) {
    // subscription has been cancelled
  }
});
```

However, make sure you run this function *after* subHandle has been defined. This computation will not register with a reactive dependency until it calls subHandle.ready().

Comment: It is false before it is ready and after it is cancelled. I need only the latter.

Comment: You could set something (a session hash) to true when its live & then use this to see when its no longer live so its only with the latter

Comment: I edited my answer so it only does something when the subscription has been cancelled.

Comment: @travellingprog,  Cancelled or simply not ready yet. Am I wrong?